# Python difflib.SequenceMatcher comparison issue

Tags: python, diff

I'm trying to compare two large text strings. Each can contain approximately 15 thousand characters. I need to find replace, insert, delete, and equal with their start and end characters by comparing two strings so that further operations can be done properly.

I've also tried the difflib library, but it is not giving good results.

```
impoer difflib
para1 = "In the year 2045, the world experienced a technological revolution like never before. The advances in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had transformed every aspect of our lives. From healthcare to transportation, from education to entertainment, the impact of these innovations was profound. One of the most remarkable achievements of this era was the development of AI-powered personal assistants. These intelligent beings were capable of understanding and responding to human language with unparalleled accuracy. They could perform tasks, answer questions, and even engage in meaningful conversations. As AI continued to evolve, it became an integral part of our daily routines. People relied on AI for managing their schedules, making decisions, and even providing emotional support. It seemed that there was no limit to what these machines could do. The ethical implications of AI's increasing dominance over human affairs became a topic of heated debate. While some celebrated the convenience and progress it brought, others raised concerns about privacy, security, and the potential loss of human jobs. Despite the ongoing discussions and debates, AI's influence in our lives kept growing. It was a world where humans and machines coexisted, sometimes harmoniously and sometimes with friction. The future was uncertain, but one thing was clear: technology had forever changed the course of human history. This is the end of Text 1."
para2 = "In the year 2045, the world went through a technological revolution of unprecedented proportions. The leaps in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had completely reshaped all aspects of our existence. From medical care to transportation, from learning to entertainment, the impact of these innovations was profound. One of the most extraordinary accomplishments of this era was the emergence of AI-driven personal assistants. These intelligent entities had the capability to comprehend and react to human language with remarkable precision. They could execute tasks, provide answers to queries, and even engage in substantial conversations. As AI kept progressing, it turned into an essential element of our everyday lives. People depended on AI for handling their schedules, making choices, and even offering emotional support. It seemed as if there were no boundaries to the potential of these machines. The moral questions surrounding AI's growing authority over human affairs became a subject of fervent discussion. While some celebrated the convenience and advancement it brought, others expressed worries about privacy, security, and the possible loss of human employment. Despite the continuous conversations and debates, AI's sway over our lives continued to expand. It was a world where humans and machines coexisted, sometimes peacefully and at times with friction. The future remained uncertain, but one thing was evident: technology had permanently altered the trajectory of human history. This is the end of Text 2."

op = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, para1, para2)
op.get_opcodes()
```

Output -

```
[('equal', 0, 28, 0, 28),
 ('insert', 28, 28, 28, 207),
 ('equal', 28, 30, 207, 209),
 ('replace', 30, 83, 209, 215),
 ('equal', 83, 86, 215, 218),
 ('replace', 86, 125, 218, 253),
 ('equal', 125, 127, 253, 255),
 ('replace', 127, 135, 255, 285),
 ('equal', 135, 137, 285, 287),
 ('replace', 137, 196, 287, 331),
 ('equal', 196, 198, 331, 333),
 ('replace', 198, 297, 333, 390),
 ('equal', 297, 302, 390, 395),
 ('replace', 302, 383, 395, 408),
 ('equal', 383, 390, 408, 415),
 ('replace', 390, 392, 415, 531),
 ('equal', 392, 393, 531, 532),
 ('replace', 393, 417, 532, 556),
 ('equal', 417, 422, 556, 561),
 ('replace', 422, 437, 561, 633),
 ('equal', 437, 438, 633, 634),
 ('replace', 438, 607, 634, 641),
 ('equal', 607, 630, 641, 664),
 ('replace', 630, 649, 664, 680),
 ('equal', 649, 654, 680, 685),
 ('replace', 654, 697, 685, 737),
 ('equal', 697, 708, 737, 748),
 ('replace', 708, 712, 748, 754),
 ('equal', 712, 725, 754, 767),
 ('replace', 725, 730, 767, 772),
 ('equal', 730, 758, 772, 800),
 ('replace', 758, 766, 800, 806),
 ('equal', 766, 778, 806, 818),
 ('replace', 778, 784, 818, 823),
 ('equal', 784, 817, 823, 856),
 ('replace', 817, 821, 856, 861),
 ('equal', 821, 829, 861, 869),
 ('replace', 829, 872, 869, 921),
 ('equal', 872, 878, 921, 927),
 ('replace', 878, 901, 927, 954),
 ('equal', 901, 907, 954, 960),
 ('replace', 907, 927, 960, 977),
 ('equal', 927, 956, 977, 1006),
 ('replace', 956, 974, 1006, 1008),
 ('equal', 974, 975, 1008, 1009),
 ('replace', 975, 978, 1009, 1035),
 ('equal', 978, 1022, 1035, 1079),
 ('replace', 1022, 1030, 1079, 1090),
 ('equal', 1030, 1050, 1090, 1110),
 ('replace', 1050, 1064, 1110, 1126),
 ('equal', 1064, 1101, 1126, 1163),
 ('replace', 1101, 1125, 1163, 1166),
 ('equal', 1125, 1126, 1166, 1167),
 ('replace', 1126, 1127, 1167, 1194),
 ('equal', 1127, 1141, 1194, 1208),
 ('replace', 1141, 1156, 1208, 1228),
 ('equal', 1156, 1179, 1228, 1251),
 ('replace', 1179, 1210, 1251, 1252),
 ('equal', 1210, 1211, 1252, 1253),
 ('replace', 1211, 1214, 1253, 1290),
 ('equal', 1214, 1278, 1290, 1354),
 ('replace', 1278, 1299, 1354, 1372),
 ('equal', 1299, 1331, 1372, 1404),
 ('insert', 1331, 1331, 1404, 1438),
 ('equal', 1331, 1335, 1438, 1442),
 ('replace', 1335, 1369, 1442, 1449),
 ('equal', 1369, 1386, 1449, 1466),
 ('replace', 1386, 1412, 1466, 1500),
 ('equal', 1412, 1455, 1500, 1543),
 ('replace', 1455, 1456, 1543, 1544),
 ('equal', 1456, 1457, 1544, 1545)]
```

In above output, it is mentioned `('insert', 28, 28, 28, 207)` which means after character position 28, one string got added as:

```
para2[28:207]

'went through a technological revolution of unprecedented proportions. The leaps in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had completely reshaped all aspects of our '
```

but in actual 'experienced' updated to 'went through' and after it from char position 41, 'a technological revolution' is the equal in both strings, which was not captured.

I've tried it by converting it into a list and then comparing it, but it was not very helpful. `get_opcodes` has all the information I need, but the results are very incorrect. Is there a workaround, another library available, or any NLP approach to be able to get good results?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround may be to convert the strings into sequences of words instead, which produces much fewer surprises to humans than character-based edits:

```
import difflib

para1 = "In the year 2045, the world experienced a technological revolution like never before. The advances in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had transformed every aspect of our lives. From healthcare to transportation, from education to entertainment, the impact of these innovations was profound. One of the most remarkable achievements of this era was the development of AI-powered personal assistants. These intelligent beings were capable of understanding and responding to human language with unparalleled accuracy. They could perform tasks, answer questions, and even engage in meaningful conversations. As AI continued to evolve, it became an integral part of our daily routines. People relied on AI for managing their schedules, making decisions, and even providing emotional support. It seemed that there was no limit to what these machines could do. The ethical implications of AI's increasing dominance over human affairs became a topic of heated debate. While some celebrated the convenience and progress it brought, others raised concerns about privacy, security, and the potential loss of human jobs. Despite the ongoing discussions and debates, AI's influence in our lives kept growing. It was a world where humans and machines coexisted, sometimes harmoniously and sometimes with friction. The future was uncertain, but one thing was clear: technology had forever changed the course of human history. This is the end of Text 1."
para2 = "In the year 2045, the world went through a technological revolution of unprecedented proportions. The leaps in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had completely reshaped all aspects of our existence. From medical care to transportation, from learning to entertainment, the impact of these innovations was profound. One of the most extraordinary accomplishments of this era was the emergence of AI-driven personal assistants. These intelligent entities had the capability to comprehend and react to human language with remarkable precision. They could execute tasks, provide answers to queries, and even engage in substantial conversations. As AI kept progressing, it turned into an essential element of our everyday lives. People depended on AI for handling their schedules, making choices, and even offering emotional support. It seemed as if there were no boundaries to the potential of these machines. The moral questions surrounding AI's growing authority over human affairs became a subject of fervent discussion. While some celebrated the convenience and advancement it brought, others expressed worries about privacy, security, and the possible loss of human employment. Despite the continuous conversations and debates, AI's sway over our lives continued to expand. It was a world where humans and machines coexisted, sometimes peacefully and at times with friction. The future remained uncertain, but one thing was evident: technology had permanently altered the trajectory of human history. This is the end of Text 2."
para1 = para1.split()
para2 = para2.split()
for m in difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, para1, para2).get_matching_blocks():
    print(' '.join(para1[m.a:m.a + m.size]))
```

This outputs:

```
In the year 2045, the world
a technological revolution
The
in artificial intelligence, robotics, and biotechnology had
...
```

You can then convert word-based edits back to character-based edits if you want.

Comment: but it'll return only common strings. for other op codes like insert, delete and replace I won't be having enough information for it. I've tried split() also but its giving incorrect results for the end of the string (something related to full-stop).